# How to use google drive api in django for authentication and file storage?

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api, django-allauth, django-storage

How can I use google drive api as authentication as well file storage in django?

I want to save files that they upload to their own google drive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.